# why Spring mvc redirect not working well?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@PostMapping("/regist")
public String regist(Person person, Model model) {
    Person p = new Person("name", "age");
    model.addAttribute("person", p); //add person to model
    model.addAttribute("hobby", "reading);
    return "redirect:/info";
}

@GetMapping("/info")
public String info() {
    return "result";
}
```

Why (person) model.addAttribute("person", p) not appended to url like (hobby) when redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

Model attributes are not used for redirects. Have a look at [RedirectAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) instead.

> A specialization of the Model interface that controllers can use to
> select attributes for a redirect scenario. Since the intent of adding
> redirect attributes is very explicit -- i.e. to be used for a redirect
> URL, attribute values may be formatted as Strings and stored that way
> to make them eligible to be appended to the query string or expanded
> as URI variables in org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView.
> This interface also provides a way to add flash attributes. For a
> general overview of flash attributes see FlashMap. You can use
> RedirectAttributes to store flash attributes and they will be
> automatically propagated to the "output" FlashMap of the current
> request.
>
> Example usage in an @Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String handle(Account account, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
   if (result.hasErrors()) {
     return "accounts/new";
   }
   // Save account ...
   redirectAttrs.addAttribute("id", account.getId()).addFlashAttribute("message", "Account created!");
   return "redirect:/accounts/{id}";
 }
```

> A RedirectAttributes model is
> empty when the method is called and is never used unless the method
> returns a redirect view name or a RedirectView.
>
> After the redirect, flash attributes are automatically added to the
> model of the controller that serves the target URL.